# Reading SHORT date from System Properties

Tags: java, locale, date-format

Is it possible using java to read configured `SHORT` date format from System properties?

For example, I configured the system locale as `en_US` (`SHORT` date applicable for US locale is `M/d/yy`). But if I change the `SHORT` date format from `M/d/yy` to `yyyy-MM-dd` in windows, then how will I read the configured `SHORT` date format from system properties using java?

The following snippet will always fetch the locale from system properties and displays the date in `SHORT` format applicable for the selected locale.

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(  
                     DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.getDefault() );

System.out.println( df.format( new Date() ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like Java allows this by any other way apart from reading the below registry key HKEY_USERS.Default\Control Panel\International\sShortDate and getting the pattern for SHORT and using it in Date functions.

Comment: **Even when i read from registry, it gives me the SHORT date format applicable for the locale (always fixed for a locale) not the configured short date format for that locale.**